# How to create a horizontal stacked bar box in shiny / shinydashboard

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard

In the [Shiny dashboard tutorial](https://wikitech-static.wikimedia.org/wiki/Building_a_Shiny_Dashboard) of the Wikimedia foundation a screenshot is shown with a kind of horizontal stacked bar (the one with red, green, and blue "Full-text...OpenSearch..Prefix):

[image: KPI Dashboard]

I have been searching everywhere, but I cannot find out how to create a bar like this. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: This could be done with `ggplot2`. See http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_bar.html. You would want a stacked bar, coord_flip, without setting an x aesthetic I think. That may be a bit cryptic until you get used to working with ggplot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a great answer, but it works. Requires learning some `ggplot2` if you want to tweak it, and I tried to get rid of the border around the edges but it isn't gone completely. Still, the basic idea is here.

```
library(ggplot2)

mydf <- data.frame(labels = c('This', 'that', 'the other'),
                   percents = c(0.31, 0.15, 0.54))

mydf$pos <- pmax(0, cumsum(mydf$percents) - (0.5 * mydf$percents))

p <- ggplot(mydf, aes(x = NA, y = percents)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', aes(fill = percents)) +
  geom_text(color = 'white', aes(label = labels, y = pos)) +
  coord_flip() +
  guides(fill = FALSE) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme_void()

png('this_plot.png', width = 800, height = 30)
p
dev.off()
```

Comment: I'm not too happy with this method, but as I am currently using your suggestion for lack of other options, I am going to accept your answer. Thanks.